# Using MethodInvokingFactoryBean for XMLConfiguration to loading file in Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean, xml-configuration, method-invocation

I have a xmlConfiguration bean to loading a SystemProperty.xml file as below

```
<bean
    id="xmlConfiguration"
    class="org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration"
    lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <value>SystemProperty.xml</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="expressionEngine">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.xpath.XPathExpressionEngine" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

It works fine, however, I have to set delimiterParsingDisabled to true in XMLConfiguration, so I change bean for adding a propery `delimiterParsingDisabled`

```
<bean
    id="xmlConfiguration"
    class="org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration"
    lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <value>SystemProperty.xml</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="expressionEngine">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.xpath.XPathExpressionEngine" />
    </property>
    <property name="delimiterParsingDisabled">
        <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But, this wouldn't work well. Due to the `setDelimiterParsingDisabled()` must be called before loading in the file. Therefore, I have to call `load(String fileName)` of XMLConfiguration after called `setDelimiterParsingDisabled()`

I have used `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` for this way, but got any exception as below

```
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: No file name has been set!
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:409)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractHierarchicalFileConfiguration.save(AbstractHierarchicalFileConfiguration.java:214)
at devicemanage.system.SystemConfigurationServiceImpl.saveSystemProperty(SystemConfigurationServiceImpl.java:232)
at datacollection.service.DataCollectionServiceImpl.syncWithDataCollection(DataCollectionServiceImpl.java:786)
at devicemanage.utility.SyncWithDCListener$1.run(SyncWithDCListener.java:51)
```

It seems that the file doesn't be set into XMLConfiguration, my `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` has described as below

```
<bean id="xmlConfigurationMethodInvokingBean"  
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">  
     <property name="targetObject" ref="xmlConfiguration" />  
     <property name="targetMethod" value="load" />
     <property name="arguments" value="SystemProperty.xml" />  
 </bean>
```

And of cause, change my `xmlConfiguration` bean to not loading file while new the constructor as below

```
<bean
    id="xmlConfiguration"
    class="org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="expressionEngine">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.xpath.XPathExpressionEngine" />
    </property>
    <property name="delimiterParsingDisabled">
        <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Not sure is that I have the wrong way to using `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` or I have an error used of the arguments to passing a fileName String into `load()`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way**

I would suggest you to create your own inherited class and declare `init-method`:

```
package beans;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;

public class CustomXMLConfiguration extends XMLConfiguration {

    private String loadFileName;

    private void init() throws ConfigurationException {
        this.load(fileName);
    }

    public String getLoadFileName() {
        return loadFileName;
    }

    public void setLoadFileName(String fileName) {
        this.loadFileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

And into the configuration you can use this class in the following way:

```
<bean id="xmlConfiguration" class="beans.CustomXMLConfiguration" lazy-init="true"
                            init-method="init">
    <property name="expressionEngine">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.tree.xpath.XPathExpressionEngine" />
    </property>
    <property name="delimiterParsingDisabled">
        <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="loadFileName" value="SystemProperty.xml"/>
</bean>
```

`init()` method will be invoked right after bean will be initialized.

**Second way**

You can use bean of `MethodInvokingBean` [class](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingBean.html). Bean of this class just invoking of target method:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="xmlConfiguration"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="load"/>
    <property name="arguments" value="SystemProperty.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Personally I would prefer first variant, because of more flexible customization and there is not redundant instance of bean. But you can choose anyone.

Hope this will be helpful.